# Different responses in different environments

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, websphere, websphere-7

I have two environments - local and UAT which are a SOAP web service is deployed on WAS 7. The response in the **local env. is proper as it sends only the fault** but the **uat is sending what is sent in the request + fault** which is undesirable

**LOCAL**

*request*

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/schema/transport/v1">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:TransportInformationRequest>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <v1:ChassisNumber>9181398</v1:ChassisNumber>
      </v1:TransportInformationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

*response*

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Faults indicating that the consumer agent is failed by a authentication or authorization mechanism.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <SecurityFault>
               <FaultTypeDescription>Faults indicating that the consumer agent is failed by a authentication or authorization mechanism.</FaultTypeDescription>
               <CustomMessage>Security header not present in the SOAP request</CustomMessage>
            </SecurityFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**UAT**

**request**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/schema/transport/v1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:TransportInformationRequest>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <v1:ChassisNumber>9181398</v1:ChassisNumber>
      </v1:TransportInformationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

*response*

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/schema/transport/v1">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:TransportInformationRequest>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <v1:ChassisNumber>9181398</v1:ChassisNumber>
      </v1:TransportInformationRequest>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Faults indicating that the consumer agent is failed by a authentication or authorization mechanism.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <SecurityFault>
               <FaultTypeDescription>Faults indicating that the consumer agent is failed by a authentication or authorization mechanism.</FaultTypeDescription>
               <CustomMessage>Security header not present in the SOAP request</CustomMessage>
            </SecurityFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The only difference we could spot was the local env. returns 3 namespaces xsd, xsi and soapenc in soapenvelope while UAT returns only v1 namespace.

The WSDL is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="TransportInformationService" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sch="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/schema/transport/v1"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:fault="http://xmlns.scania.com/common/schema/fault/v4"
    xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/contract/transport/v1"
    xmlns:tns1="http://xmlns.scania.com/productdev/contract/part/v1"
    targetNamespace="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/contract/transport/v1">

    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/schema/transport/v1"
                schemaLocation="logistics_transport_v1.xsd" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>

    <message name="GetTransportInformationRequest">
        <part element="sch:TransportInformationRequest" name="parameters" />
    </message>

    <message name="GetTransportInformationResponse">
        <part element="sch:TransportInformationResponse" name="parameters" />
    </message>

    <message name="EmptyChasisInformationFault">
        <part element="sch:EmptyChasisFault" name="fault" />
    </message>

    <message name="UnknownServerFault">
        <part name="UnknownServerFault" element="sch:UnknownServerFault" />
    </message>

    <message name="RequestMessageFormatFault">
        <part name="RequestMessageFormatFault" element="sch:RequestMessageFormatFault" />
    </message>

    <message name="NonExistingEntityFault">
        <part name="NonExistingEntityFault" element="sch:NonExistingEntityFault" />
    </message>

    <message name="SystemResourceUnavailableFault">
        <part name="SystemResourceUnavailableFault" element="sch:SystemResourceUnavailableFault" />
    </message>

    <message name="SecurityFault">
        <part name="SecurityFault" element="sch:SecurityFault" />
    </message>


    <portType name="TransportInformationDelegate">
        <operation name="GetTransportInformation">
            <input message="tns:GetTransportInformationRequest" />
            <output message="tns:GetTransportInformationResponse" />
            <fault message="tns:EmptyChasisInformationFault" name="EmptyChasisInformationFault"/>
            <fault name="SystemResourceUnavailableFault" message="tns:SystemResourceUnavailableFault"/>
            <fault name="NonExistingEntityFault" message="tns:NonExistingEntityFault"/>
            <fault name="RequestMessageFormatFault" message="tns:RequestMessageFormatFault"/>
            <fault name="UnknownServerFault" message="tns:UnknownServerFault"/>
            <fault name="SecurityFault" message="tns:SecurityFault"/>
        </operation>

    </portType>

    <binding name="TransportInformationPortBinding" type="tns:TransportInformationDelegate">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="GetTransportInformation">
            <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/contract/transport/v1/GetTransportInformation" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
            <fault name="EmptyChasisInformationFault">
                <soap:fault name="EmptyChasisInformationFault" use="literal" />
            </fault>
            <fault name="SystemResourceUnavailableFault">
                <soap:fault name="SystemResourceUnavailableFault" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
            <fault name="NonExistingEntityFault">
                <soap:fault name="NonExistingEntityFault" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
            <fault name="RequestMessageFormatFault">
                <soap:fault name="RequestMessageFormatFault" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
            <fault name="UnknownServerFault">
                <soap:fault name="UnknownServerFault" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
            <fault name="SecurityFault">
                <soap:fault name="SecurityFault" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>

    </binding>

    <service name="TransportInformationService">
        <port binding="tns:TransportInformationPortBinding" name="TransportInformationPort">
            <soap:address
                location="http://localhost:9081/SoleilWS.WEB/TransportInformationService" />
        </port>
    </service>

</definitions>
```

The xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:types="http://ws.soleil.scania.com/"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/schema/transport/v1"
    targetNamespace="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/schema/transport/v1">

    <xs:complexType name="chassisInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ChassisNumber" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="TransportLegs" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="From" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="To" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="OutsideEU" type="xs:boolean" />
                        <xs:element name="ModeOfTransport" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="NameOfTransport" type="xs:string"
                            minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="NationalityOfTransport" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:documentation>Two character ISO 3166-1 code for the
                                            nationality of the transport
                                        </xs:documentation>
                                    </xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:length value="2" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Departure" type="xs:dateTime"
                            minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="EstimateTimeOfArrival" type="xs:dateTime"
                            minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>



    <xs:element name="TransportInformationRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ChassisNumber" type="xs:int" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="TransportInformationResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Chassis" type="chassisInfo" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="EmptyChasisFault">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="CustomMessage">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="FaultTypeDescription">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="RequestMessageFormatFault">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element
                fixed="Request message format validation fault. Note that there may be other fault message types capturing faults for more specific request message problems."
                name="FaultTypeDescription" type="FaultTypeDescription" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CustomMessage" type="CustomMessage" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="SystemResourceUnavailableFault">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element
                fixed="Faults which are of temporary character and not caused by incorrect request messages. This message may be used to communicate that the client can expect an invocation with the same request message to work at a later time. Example: required resource of the service realization, such as a database or another service, is temporarily inaccessible."
                name="FaultTypeDescription" type="FaultTypeDescription" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CustomMessage" type="CustomMessage" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="UnknownServerFault">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element
                    fixed="Faults which are not classified to any other category. Note that there may be, although so should be avoided when possible, other undeclared fault message types as well."
                    name="FaultTypeDescription" type="FaultTypeDescription" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CustomMessage" type="CustomMessage" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="NonExistingEntityFault">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element
                fixed="Faults indicating that the request message is referencing an entity not existing in the service datastore."
                name="FaultTypeDescription" type="FaultTypeDescription" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CustomMessage" type="CustomMessage" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="InvalidReferenceFault">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This fault may be extended using specific faults
                for specific, or specific groups of, foreign keys.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element
                fixed="Faults indicating that the entity contained in the request has an invalid reference to another entity."
                name="FaultTypeDescription" type="FaultTypeDescription" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CustomMessage" type="CustomMessage" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="NotSupportedForEntityStateFault">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This fault may be extended using specific faults
                for specific, or specific groups of, state-machine rules.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element
                fixed="Faults indicating that the operation issued on an entity is not permitted due to the state of the same entity."
                name="FaultTypeDescription" type="FaultTypeDescription" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CustomMessage" type="CustomMessage" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="SecurityFault">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This fault may be extended for specific security
                faults. Remember, however, that revealing too much information on
                the inner workings of a security mechanism in fault messages may
                risk the security of the solution.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element
                fixed="Faults indicating that the consumer agent is failed by a authentication or authorization mechanism."
                name="FaultTypeDescription" type="FaultTypeDescription" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CustomMessage" type="CustomMessage" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Why the difference between the responses ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference in the environments? Check the WAS service pack level, JVM service pack level, feature pack versions, WAS config, etc. Do both environments have the same network access?

Do your logfiles show any differences? Perhaps you can increase logging levels or turn on WAS tracing to identify the cause of the errant behaviour.